# How can I check if a value appears in a different table more efficiently?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, subquery

I am able to fetch the neccesary results with the query I have written below. Sadly this requires me to go through a huge table with a subquery which takes over 10 seconds every time the query is executed. Would there be a more efficient way to do this?

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT replace( CATEGORY, '-', '' ) 
FROM `LISTINGS`) LIMIT 0 , 30
```

As a note: the category value is written as '-1-' in the table LISTINGS, where 1 is the category ID.

Comment: You could try eliminating the replace with something like `where '-'+ID+'-' in (select distinct category ..` - my syntax might be wrong, you may need to convert ID to varchar to do that. Looks like you do have to scan that table no matter what though.

Comment: Do the categories change often?  If not, just save the category IDs in memcache and query using the IDs.  Or even save the entire category objects in memcache.  In typical usage there shouldn't be a reason to fetch categories from the DB when serving to the end user.

Answer (score 2):

You can first try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CATEGORIES c
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM `LISTINGS` l
              WHERE c.id = replace(l.CATEGORY, '-', '' ) 
             )
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Some versions of MySQL implement the `in` in a very inefficient manner, so this might fix the problem.

If not, then try adding an index `listings(category)` and doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM CATEGORIES c
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM `LISTINGS` l
              WHERE concat('-', c.id, '-') = l.CATEGORY
             )
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

This "inverts" the comparison, but allows MySQL to use the index for the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the huge table is LISTINGS and that CATEGORY field from it is a index.

You need to lose DISTINCT REPLACE.

```
DISTINCT REPLACE (index_field,'a','b') // Using index; Using temporary
```

This first replaces all the values and then checks for distinct.
Given the fact that the field LISTINGS.CATEGORY doesn't have
problem values like '-1' and '-1-' you can use distinct like

```
DISTINCT index_field // Using index for group-by, faster
```

AND concat the field from the table CATEGORIES (which i suppose has much fewer records):

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CONCAT('-',ID,'-') IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(CATEGORY) FROM `LISTINGS`)
```

You can also consider losing the "-" 's for good.